# Shopify "test" template page

Tags: shopify

Is there any way to publish a test template page?  For example, if I have a template file called "cart-test.liquid," is there anything I can modify so I can navigate to "http://shopname.com/cart-test" in order to test it out?

I'm currently developing an widget that'll be included on Shopify cart pages, and one of my clients wants to test it out before it's published on their real cart page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to test a theme without editing the live theme is to duplicate the current theme and use the preview function.

From within the Shopify admin (using Shopify Admin 2) goto the "Themes" section. Here you can "duplicate" the published main theme. It will create a copy of the theme within the "Unpublished themes" section. Here you can edit it and also get a preview of this theme (click on the link preview).

Comment: What a terribly asinine oversight - I don't know why I didn't think of this!  I'll let my client know.  Thanks!